# Add a custom column in django database

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-database

Iam little new to Django and Iam struggling to add column in Django Database.

I was working to create a subcategory for products, but the I want those subcategories to be predefined. That is for example "Fashion" category could have subcategory of 'Men', 'Women', 'Kids'.

I want a table in DB of these subcategories, without having the user or admin panel option to manipulate these field. User can only select article belong to which subcategory.

I go through a few documentation, but could understood much:
1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-model-fields/
2. [Adding fields to an already existing database for Django (version < 1.7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150493/adding-fields-to-an-already-existing-database-for-django-version-1-7)

Please suggest me how to add these predefined table values.

Answer (score 0):

Create subcategories model and model admin then in model admin you can disable change permission like this

**Subcategories admin model**

```
def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    return False
```

Now you can add,delete and view only permission. User and admin can't change them.