# How to assign a user to a model in my database

Tags: python, django, database, class, model

```
    from django.db import models
    from datetime import datetime
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

    User = get_user_model()


    class Blog(models.Model): 
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        headline = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        content = models.CharField(max_length=2050)
        time_created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username
```

every time I migrate this

"(venv) PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\APPS\web_app_project> python manage.py makemigrations"

I always get this message:

"It is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'user' to blog without specifying a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.
Please select a fix:

1. Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
2. Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.

Select an option:"

How do I go about this

Comment: Can your blog object be without user assigned or does it always have user assigned?

Comment: The plan is to make anybody post whatever, but only the admin can access and verify if it's worthy of being on the blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've added the non-nullable field `user` to `Blog` Django needs to add a user to *all* instances of blogs in the database, both new ones and existing. If you've created a blog instance in the database, what should Django do with its new user column? That's what it is asking you.

*Only if there is no data in the database or you are **completely** OK with losing data,* you can migrate your app to zero with `python manage.py migrate <your app name> zero` (You might want to reverse to migration besides `zero`. You can [read more about reverse migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#reversing-migrations-1)). This will effectively undo all of your migrations for that app. You can then delete the existing migrations for that app and run `makemigrations` again. Django will no longer complain about the non-nullable field `user`, as this results in a migration that *creates* a `Blog` table with a user field, instead of a migration that attempts to add a `user` field to *an existing* `Blog` table. Once again, *do not do this unless you are OK with losing data.* This should *never* be done if your app is already running in production, but it is OK if you have never deployed the app and have no "real" data, and you are still in the initial development phase. Also, make sure you have a backup of deleted migrations in case you need to add them back.

As others have suggested, you can create a default user model that is used as the one-time default to add `user`s to `Blogs`. For example (in Django shell)

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()
user = User(username='default_blog_user')
user.set_unusable_password() # Nobody should be able to log in as this user
user.save()
print(user.id) # keep this ID
```

Then, in the migration, you can use whatever that `user.id` value was as the one-time-default. But this once again assumes that you haven't deployed to production, as the one-time-default and the IDs in development and production may not match.

If you have already deployed to production, I think the only thing you can do is make the user field nullable for the sake of your migration, but assert that it is *not* null in your programming logic. For example, by [adding a validator to the field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/validators/).

---

Side note: instead of running `get_user_model` in your `models` module, you should do this:

```py
from django.conf import settings

class Blog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # etc.
```

> When you define a foreign key or many-to-many relations to the user model, you should specify the custom model using the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting.

[source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model)

Comment: How then can I use the "django.conf.settings" in the shell terminal

Comment: In your shell terminal you would want to use `get_user_model`, as `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` is just a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably get away with adding the user manually by using the `python shell`• `python manage.py shell` then import the required models.

- Read more from a similar question [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#shell):
- How to use the [python shell](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#shell)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5150535/15383032

Comment: That means I have to be the one assigning the users to the models myself. How can i make it work with my absence

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add a UUID to your User Model and make the fields that require a user in other models a CharField that stores the Users UUID.

Comment: Can you help me by showing me in "code" how to add the UUID